# jQuery - cloning and manipulating variables

Tags: jquery, wordpress, variables, clone, extend

I'm attempting to troubleshoot an old Wordpress plugin that uses jQuery to do some variable manipulation. The original code is as follows:

```
            var p = $(this).parents('.postbox'); /*wp*/
            var the_name = $(this).attr('class').match(/docopy-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/i)[1];
            var the_group = $('.wpa_group-'+ the_name +':first.tocopy', p);
            var the_clone = the_group.clone().removeClass('tocopy last');
```

I don't believe the clone function is working correctly. My test code is as follows:

```
            var the_name = "name";
            console.log(the_name);
            var the_group = $('.wpa_group-'+ the_name +':first.tocopy');
            console.log(the_group);             
            var the_clone = the_group.clone().removeClass('tocopy last');
            console.log(the_clone);
            var the_clone_test = the_group.clone();
            console.log(the_clone_test);
```

Neither the original clone function (with the removeClass) or my clone test return any data to the console. Am I missing something really simple here? I don't believe the code has been modified since the site was built, but WordPress or jQuery versions may have changed in the meantime.

Comment: Does the_group return any data? And if it is, what kind of data?

Comment: Did you try `var the_group = $('.wpa_group-'+ the_name +':first.tocopy, p');` ?

Comment: @spoq The console log of the_group returns this: `[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".wpa_group-name:first.tocopy"]`, but the rest of the variables come up blank.

Comment: @dingo_d I added logging to the live site as well to make sure I wasn't breaking something by modifying that code for test use. I still get blank variables after cloning.